# Storing a "apply" or "call" function in a variable - in JS

Tags: javascript, apply

```js
const j = Object.prototype.valueOf.apply

console.log(typeof j); // "function"
console.log(Object.prototype.valueOf.apply === j); // true

console.log(Object.prototype.valueOf.apply(3)); // WORKS
console.log(j(3)); // ERROR! TypeError: j is not a function
```

I found something weird situation in JS, about `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call` function. Without storing `apply` function in variable, it works. But when I store `apply` function to variable, it doesn't work.

What causes this weird situation?

Comment: That is what I get as error: "Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply called on incompatible undefined"

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type

Comment: `apply` is not bound to `valueOf`.

Comment: Typescript gives this additional error: `The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Function'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apply` expects to be called as a method of a function. (i.e. `someFunction.apply(...)`). This would make the `this` value that function.

When you copy `apply` to `j` and then call `j()`; the `this` value is the default value (typically `window` if you are running in a browser).

That value is not a function.